# I'm not seeing a dark blue color on my mesh in my weight painting mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode, vertex-weights

In all the tutorials I have been studying, as soon as someone enters weight paint mode in blender, their mesh turns dark blue. Mine is not turning dark blue at all, and when I applied automatic weights to my mesh, my mesh began to droop. Any idea whats going on? My rig works fine, I just can't seem to get the weights to work right now or the blue color to show up. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: You are in material view right now. Go into solid mode: press Z + 6. To go back press Z and choose the mode ore use the little balls in the upper right corner

Comment: Thank you! I got to material mode, but I'm still not seeing that dark blue color. Just my normal gray mesh. My weight painting brush has no effect either. Do I need to select something I don't have selected? Or could it be another issue?

Comment: It could be a bug, try going to paint weight mode in a new file on the default cube. If it works try appending your meshes to the new file.

Comment: Ok! Thank you, Alex!